# How to multi threading on webBrowser DocumentCompleted?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//list of tasks
}

private void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//list of tasks
}
```

see above.
my question is, how to make both of them to run at the same time(make two threads to manually control the monitoring of them), now the problem is they all runs separately on the main thread, and i can'd do other tasks, thanks for the helps! sorry about the bad english

and i have tried to use, for example:

```
    Thread threadw1 = new Thread(() => webBrowser1.Navigate("url1"));
    Thread threadw2 = new Thread(() => webBrowser2.Navigate("url2"));
    threadw1.Start();
    threadw2.Start();
```

but that is to use threads to navigate, once the navigation is done, then the system runs the document completed separately.
and i dont know how to control them, thanks for the help!

i have wrapped the tasks in a function and now the problem is 
when i do this, it doesn't work

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.ReadyState < WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;

                // Do the work, you have the event args in ev


            Thread wbb1 = new Thread(() => wb1task());
            wbb1.Start();
            //wb1task();
        }
```

but when i do this it works, but it becomes a single thread again:

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.ReadyState < WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;

                // Do the work, you have the event args in ev


            //Thread wbb1 = new Thread(() => wb1task());
           // wbb1.Start();
            wb1task();
        }
```

the thread started then the document completed, i need something to hold after wbb1.Start(); to prevent it to go out of the loop:)

ok this solves the problem, thanks everyone!

```
wbb1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

Comment: i have tried to create a thread to handle it, but the function is called automatically after the page loaded completely, and i dont know how to trigger or monitor them manually.

Comment: I suggest you create your threads in the DocumentCompleted functions and have those threads call the function/s to perform the list of tasks (if they are not GUI tasks)

Comment: This is only possible if you create the WebBrowser object on another thread.  A special thread, it must meet the STA contract.  Covered by:

Comment: wrap them inside a function then create a thread to run it is probably the valid way, i think i will try it out

Answer (score 0):

Put your tasks to run inside the handlers for `DocumentCompleted` event. I used a thread because you mentioned it. I suggest using either `ThreadPool` or `Task`.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    new Thread((state) => {
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs ev = 
                (WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) state;
        // Do the work, you have the event args in ev

    }) {Name = "Thread for webBrowser1"}.Start(e);
}
```

Comment: If the page navigates away while the code in your thread is running, that will happen. Are you sure you are staying on the same page?

Comment: I don't understand: what do you want to do with a page that is being immediately changed after DocumentCompleted.

Comment: oh no, in fact, it is still on the same page, now i am confused again

Comment: i have edited it above, i have only used a thread to wrap them, so strange, i think is the thread is trying to run before the page loaded

Comment: "When the DocumentCompleted event occurs, the new document is fully loaded, which means you can access its contents through the Document, DocumentText, or DocumentStream property" MSDN says

Comment: basically navigating through pages and fill the form then submit, 2 browsers operates at the same time, i think i need to mark them as STA , but i dont know how to do that

Comment: I don't think STA to be your problem, but anyway apply `[STAThread]` attribute to the entry point of your application (usually `Main()`)

Comment: the problem is message pump stuck, i need to pass the webbrowser object into a new thread as Hans Passant mentioned above

Comment: wbb1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA) this solves the problem